# How to check that the host name matches Common Name in SSL certificate in PHP?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

With this PHP script

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sf.net/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
if (!curl_exec($ch)) {
    echo "Error #" . curl_errno($ch) . ": " . curl_error($ch);
}
?>
```

I got no error. This seems to be OK.

The expected result should an error message indicating  that certificate name `sourceforge.net` does not match expected `sf.net`. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you access sf.net you get the certificate for sf.net and not for sourceforge.net. The certificate for sf.net has as CN `*.sf.net` and as SAN `DNS:*.sf.net, DNS:sf.net`. This means that the certificate matches the URL. Don't get confused from the following redirect to `sourceforge.net` because within this redirect it will get a new certificate which is valid for the new target.

Apart from that, by setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false you will accept any certificates no matter if it was issued by a locally trusted CA or not. And it will not help that you set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` because with both settings combined you will accept a self-signed certificate for the name `sf.net` which makes man in the middle attacks trivial.

Comment: Thank you for these explanations.Do you mean that I must set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to TRUE and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`to 0?

Comment: @LeMoussel: for proper verification you should leave both at what is hopefully the default on your system, which is [verifypeer true](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html) and [verifyhost 2](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.html)